# How to run a Thread when a list becomes populated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently, I am using a system like this:

```
class Processor(object):
    """
    Makes sure that all operations the user requires to be processed are processed in order
    Also makes sure that the users are still pickle-able
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []
        self.killed = False

    def begin_processing(self):
        while not self.killed:
            if not self.tasks:
                pass
```

Basically users in a game append tasks (which is essentially a `threading.Timer`) to `tasks`. The main point of this system is to make sure that the actual user object is pickleable.

However, this is very inefficient because it is constantly checking if the queue has any tasks in it.

I would rather make it so that it only runs when a task is appended to the queue. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a message [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

```
import queue    

class Processor(object):
    """
    Makes sure that all operations the user requires to be processed are processed in order
    Also makes sure that the users are still pickle-able
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = queue.Queue()
        self.killed = False

    def begin_processing(self):
        while not self.killed:
            task = self.tasks.get()
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. I want a way that basically causes a "task added" event to cause the queue to start processing.

Comment: The thread will be stop on the `queue.get()` call and wait for a new task. If you want to do other computation, you should do them in the main process.

Comment: Oh thats more like what I was thinking. Thank you!